# Let's make some ads for other sites, 2016 edition

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Last year we [made some community-promotion ads to run on other sites](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/221/83).  I don't know how successful they've been in drawing traffic (obviously we still have growth challenges here), but it seems to me that where we haven't received *negative* feedback, it's worth continuing to try.

Last year we tried both general and question-specific ads, the latter intended to hook people with a compelling question related to the other site's scope.  That got mixed results -- on UX (where we got the idea) the ad got a lot of upvotes and complaints from one person; on The Workplace the ad is live but has gotten more negative comments (including from the same guy as on UX, so maybe he just doesn't like us).  Maybe we haven't found the right question/site combinations, or maybe we need to rethink the approach at least somewhat.  If we can find *different* specific questions I think it's worth trying that again on UX, but maybe Workplace needs a different approach.

I don't remember if any of our current ads link to specific *tags*, but that's an approach I've seen elsewhere.  So let's take a look at our tags and think about whether any of them have obvious fits with other (graduated) sites.

All that said, what ads should we submit to other sites?  Please use answers to make proposals.  Ultimately we're going to need art -- 300x250 pixels, which is a *new size requirement* -- but you don't have to wait until you have art to propose something.

Community Building is a small and underused site, but we're high-quality.  Let's figure out how to present that quality elsewhere on the network in a way that encourages people to join us.

Comment: I really wish Meta.SE had community ads.  Talk about an overlapping audience!

Comment: A lot of the people interested in this site from mSE are mods on other sites that have already heard about this site in a very special chatroom that may or may not exist (rumor says that it's hidden from the public using magical unicorns). However, I agree that it would be great to get some new traffic.

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin I want to reach beyond the denizens of that chat room.  There are communities out there in the wild, too -- let's figure out how to reach their users and organizers. :-)

Comment: We may want to avoid posting ads on the high traffic SE sites, because they would not react correctly to the low speed of answers here as of 2018. Fixing https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1354/is-there-anything-in-place-to-attract-back-past-members-of-this-community might be a first step.

Comment: @user2987828 we didn't post external ads in 2017 or (so far) 2018 because of the traffic.  We need activity to get activity but we need to find people who want to help build it and aren't just looking for a fully-active site.

Answer (score 4):

It might be worth making ads for some of our tags for related communities.  I'm making this post community wiki so we can collect ideas in one place; if anybody wants to develop any of these ideas further in a new answer, go for it.

- [user-retention](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-retention) and/or [user-engagement](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-engagement) could work on UX.
- [privacy](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/privacy), [security](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) could work on Information Security
- [web-forums](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-forums), [blog](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blog) (can we rename that "blog**s**"?), [promotion](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/promotion) could work on the website-related sites.
- [bullying](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bullying), [game](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) (can we rename that "game**s**"?) could work on Arqade.

Before proceeding with a particular tag/site pair somebody should review the current questions on that tag (at least the top several) and try to judge how somebody coming from that site would react.  We want to make a good impression, after all.

Comment: Maybe [Productivity.Se] as well? Tags social-interaction, meetings, team, collaboration, group-productivity? (That's *their* tags, maybe I misunderstand the direction)

Comment: @JanDoggen good suggestion for the future.  They're still in beta, so they don't get community ads, but someday!

Comment: @JanDoggen Personal Productivity is now closed.